# problem with easy bcd

Tags: windows-7, mbr

I tried to launch easy bcd to manage my mbr. But there's a problem. It said:

```
Easy BCD has detected that your BCD boot data and MBR are either not from the latest version
of windows vista, or don't yet exist
```

I'm currently running windows 7. I don't know why this happened. What do I do to solve this problem, and what might be the cause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Latest version of EasyBCD is from 2008. It probably doesn't even support Windows 7.
Take a look here: http://neosmart.net/changelog.php?id=1

Comment: Its compatible since I've used it before on the same os.

Comment: EasyBCD has been updated to 2.0 as of July 12, 2010. The release notes are here: http://neosmart.net/blog/2010/welcome-to-easybcd-2/

I've posted this as a new reply, too.

Answer (score 1):

See this thread where a similar problem was solved:
[Valid BCD Registry not Detected](http://neosmart.net/forums/showthread.php?t=4047)

The problem might be that EasyBCD looks for the BCD in the "active" partition, which is not where it's located.

The solution is apparently to press OK and let EasyBCD do its thing.
You may yet encounter some problems with BCDEDIT that you can work around.

(But ensure that you have backups, just in case.)

Answer (score 1):

I would like to second the advice to upgrade. I just used Easy BCD to unscramble my drives and put the boot manager back on C: where it belongs -- and here I was fearing that I may have to do a reinstall! I LOVE this product and just wish I had known of its existence a couple of years ago.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to EasyBCD 2.0: http://neosmart.net/blog/2010/welcome-to-easybcd-2/